# How can you have three columns with middle column flexible width depended

Tags: html, css

How can you have three columns with middle column flexible width depended on first column.

Example:

```
Firstname ........ John
Age .............. 39
Country .......... Germany
```

Also Is it possible to achieve such thing only with html and css?

Currently I have this code, but it is not flexible, I mean the Person Attribute might change at any point so I would like the dots column to be flexible on the first column.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.container div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.one {
  background: red;
}

.two {
  background: green;
}

.three {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="one">111111</div>
  <div class="two">.............</div>
  <div class="three">333</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you need to actually display the `..............` or are these dots here just for the layout and alignment?

Comment: i need to display  ..............  but it can be anything, what i meant i would want the middle column to be flexible in length so those dots can be a background or smth! @JeremyThille

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use table layout with some flex like below:

```css
.container {
  display:table;
}
.row {
 display:table-row;
}

.container .col {
  display: table-cell;
  position:relative;
}
.container .col:first-child span{
  display:flex;
}

.col:first-child span:after {
  content:"";
  background:radial-gradient(circle at center,#000 2px,transparent 3px)0 0 /10px 100%, yellow;
  flex:1;
  padding-right:80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col"><span>Firstname</span></div>
  <div class="col">John</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col"><span>Age</span></div>
  <div class="col">39</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col"><span>Country</span></div>
  <div class="col">Germany</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This one works too, i think it is much better solution than previous one!

Comment: @Mizlul updated my answer ;) simply use repeated radial-gradient

Comment: yeah, works great, I should accept your answer as true as it is much more flexible!

Answer (score 0):

I have prepared snipet for you which will create dotted line in between two elements. This way are dots always filling space between two containers and white background from containers is hidding dots behind them. See below how I did it:

PS: Just edit .container width to have it smaller.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 9px;
}
.container-line {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #000000;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}

.container div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.one {
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 11px;
}

.three {
  background: white;
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 11px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-line">
    <div class="one">111111</div>
    <div class="three">333</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Happy to help! :)